# Compatible Hardware for Ubuntu Budgie

Tags: drivers, nvidia, sound, graphics, 64-bit

I am wondering if Ubuntu is compatible on my computer, here is the list of hardware on it:

Brand: HP

Model: Pavilion HPE h8-1214

Motherboard:Gigabyte M3970AM-HP (Angelica)

RAM: 10gb DDR3

Chipset: AMD 970

CPU: AMD FX-6100 6 Core 3.3GHz

Audio: Integrated IDT 92HD89E Beats Audio

Video: EVGA GeForce GTX 550 Ti 2gb

This well be very helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really, the best way to tell is to create a bootable USB stick, run it and see. You can run Ubuntu without installing it, from the USB stick. This will tell you if your graphics card, wifi etc will work, before you install.

Get Ubuntu here : https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Instructions on the bootable usb here : https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu?_ga=2.77815837.844715256.1509442432-1433623884.1509442432#0

Hope it all goes well for you.

Comment: One point, make sure you read your other post, about dual boot. The BIOS with Microsofts control of UEFI can cause problems. It maybe that your machine will work with Ubuntu, but the UEFI / bios issues will stop the dual boot.

Good luck.